# Problema al instalar vstoolsforxamarin

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin

Saludos a toda la comunidad.

Tengo este problema al instalar Xamarin sobre Visual Studio 2015. No me instala todas las funciones, entre ellas la que necesito, desarrollo multiplataforma.

El mensaje que da es:

> C#/.NET (Xamarin v4.0.3)
>
> La cuenta especificada ya existe.

¿A alguien le ha pasado? Si es así, les agradecería si saben como solucionarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Archivo de log](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=16673024A8F42B52!391&authkey=!ACrPJDhkLpk6xmg&ithint=file%2Clog)

Comment: La imagen dice, "Examinar el archivo de logs", deberías incluirlo en la pregunta para tener algo de contexto.

Comment: Agregué enlace al Archivo de logs. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado: Realicé una instalación manual, tal como recomienda Xamarin, en [Xamarin.Android Manual Installation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/). Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No es un error del programa de instalación de Xamarin si no un error bastante común con instaladores.

Microsoft recomienda utilizar la herramienta FixIt en estos casos:
[Fix problems that programs cannot be installed or uninstalled](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall)

Comment: Fix It funciona con Windows 10?

Comment: No, únicamente hasta Windows 8.1